# Why I'm getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException?

Tags: java, android, email

Can someone tells me why the app throws this?

```
W/System.err: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
        at com.example.**.Utils.SendMail.doInBackground(SendMail.java:71)
        at com.example.**.Utils.SendMail.doInBackground(SendMail.java:19)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I'm trying to send a mail with javamail api.

I want to mention that I checked on the mail account, less secure apps.

This is the SendMail class

```
package com.example.****.Utils;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private Context context;
  private Session session;


  private String email;
  private String subject;
  private String message;

  public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message)
  {
      this.context = context;
      this.email = email;
      this.subject = subject;
      this.message = message;
  }

  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      Toast.makeText(context, "Sending mail...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
  {
      super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
      Toast.makeText(context, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

      session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
          protected  PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
              return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
          }
      });
      try {
          MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);
          mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
          mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
          mm.setSubject(subject);
          mm.setText(message);

          Transport.send(mm);
      }
      catch (MessagingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
  }
}
```

And here I'm using it

```
  String email = "******";
        String subject = "Activation";
        String message = "This User requires activation: " + "<a href='http://localhost:80/approve/" +mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail() +"> Click here </a>";

        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject,message);
        sm.execute();
```

I provided the right password, I checked that on my Google Account, it should be working
can you please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hey you need to add this `props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");`

Comment: I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property missing in your implementation.

Use `props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");` in your `doInBackground()` method to overcome this issue.

**Explanation:** 
[Gmail requires SSL](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en&ref_topic=7280141)
[image: google support screenshot]

From [java mail documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ.html#gmail):
The following code fragment shows a simple way to incorporate the needed configuration in your application:

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String username = "user";
String password = "passwd";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
// set any other needed mail.smtp.* properties here
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
// set the message content here
Transport.send(msg, username, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution After losing many days I found this solution. you should enable Two-Factor Authentication in your Gmail account and then create App Password by fellow these steps:

1. Go to your Google Account.
2. Select Security.
3. Under "Signing in to Google," select App Passwords. You may need to sign in. If you don’t have this option, it might be because:

- 2-Step Verification is not set up for your account.
- 2-Step Verification is only set up for security keys.
- Your account is through work, school, or other organizations.
- You turned on Advanced Protection.

4. At the bottom, choose Select app and choose the app you using and then Select the device and choose the device you’re using, and then Generate.
5. Follow the instructions to enter the App Password. The App Password is the 16-character code in the yellow bar on your device.
6. Tap Done.

after that copy the generated password and paste it into your JavaMail password section.

Good luck.